# In "The Man with the Golden Gun" why does Hip drive off without James Bond?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, the-man-with-the-golden-gun

There's a scene in [The Man with The Golden Gun](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071807/) where Bond, Hip and Hip's two nieces are fleeing from a karate school.

The four of them reach Hip's car. Hip and the girls get in and they drive away. Why did he leave Bond? Did he think they was in the car? This scene has bothered me for years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's just simple confusion.  The two girls jump into the back seat, James closes their door and starts to run around the back of the car, presumably intending to get into the front passenger seat.  Hip hear's the door slam and assumes everyone one is in and drives off!

He may not have noticed James wasn't in the car when he looked back.  Why he didn't stop top leave him into the car I don't know!

The scene can be seen in [this YouTube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnHXyHAfqLU):

Comment: Maybe. However Hip looks back before driving away and both girls look back and seem, judging by their actions (I don't know chinese) to be telling Hip he forgot James?

Comment: As stated in the answer I'm not sure why he didn't stop, I can't find a good clip showing what happens after he starts driving. Maybe the bad guys too close for him to risk stopping. As for the look back, it seems to be a quick glance over his right shoulder, more so that they'll hear him rather than to check who's in the car.  Maybe he thought James go in first, which would have put him at the far side of the car, possibly out of his line of site for the quick glance back.